# Unity3D Input Manager And Using Buttons For Input.GetAxis

Tags: c#, scripting, unity-game-engine

I just bought NGUI and need some help...

Right now my 2D character is moving left and right with the left and right arrows.
I have the left and right arrows setup to do this in the input manager.

I made left and right arrow buttons with NGUI added them to my UI Root.
How do I get it to mimic the left arrow being pressed when I press the left arrow button?
Or is there a way to add the left arrow button being pressed to the input manager?

All I want to do is make the left arrow button act like when I press the left arrow key and the same for the right.

If there is another way to do it without NGUI thats fine too.
I just want to be able to move left and right when I press the left and right buttons on a mobile device.
I have been stuck on this for like 6 hours now, and can't figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Heres an example of how I'm moving the character

```
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    // The Speed animator parameter is set to the absolute value of the horizontal input.
    anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(h));

    // If the player is changing direction (h has a different sign to velocity.x) or hasn't reached maxSpeed yet...
    if(h * rigidbody2D.velocity.x < maxSpeed)
    // ... add a force to the player.
    rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.right * h * moveForce);

    if (Mathf.Abs(rigidbody2D.velocity.x) > maxSpeed)
    rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(rigidbody2D.velocity.x) * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

The effect of the button is processed in the `OnPress (bool isDown)` function. By default, it is called everytime you hover over the button.

If I understood you correctly, you want to simulate this hovering while pressing the related arrow key on the keyboard.

In order to do this, you would have to call the `OnPress (bool isDown)` function yourself. Try to add this line to your code:

`SendMessage("OnPress", true);`

This will call the OnPress function on all scripts added to the gameobject.

To call the function on a special gameObject just add a public variable `go` and then go with `go.SendMessage("OnPress", true);`

Hope, this will help. :)